# The "socket.bind" method is not working in python

Tags: python, sockets, raw-sockets

I have written this program in python3 to inject packets through a raw socket.

```
import socket
import struct
import sys

try:
    raw_socket = socket.socket(socket.PF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(0x0800))
except socket.error as e:
    print("Error occurred while creating socket. Error code: " + e[0] + " Error message : " + e[1])
    sys.exit()

raw_socket.bind(('wlan0', socket.htons(0x0800)))
packet = struct.pack('!6s6s2s', '\xb8v?\x8b\xf5\xfe', 'l\x19\x8f\xe1j\x8c', '\x80\x00')
rawSocket.send(packet + 'Hello')
```

But whenever i run the program it shows this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rawSocketInjector.py", line 11, in <module>
    raw_socket.bind(('wlan0', socket.htons(0x0800)))
OSError: [Errno 19] No such device
```

For this line of code:

```
raw_socket.bind(('wlan0', socket.htons(0x0800)))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please list our network interfaces? I think that the problem is in interface name.
If you are using linux, try this command: `ip link show`.

Comment: This worked, I didn't have a wlan0 network interfac on my linux OS.

Comment: What interfaces do you have?

Comment: "lo",  "enp3s0f1" and "wlp2s0"

Comment: Try to put "wlp2s0" instead of  "wlan0", this should work.

Comment: this worked thank you